# Blockchain technology overview

Tags: reference, request, blockchain

I'm not a computer specialist but I'm trying to understand the basics on blockchain technology. I've read some articles about its applications but I still don't get the general picture of it. I wonder if someone could help me out by suggesting non-technical books and articles about this subject. I'm particularly interested in understanding the so-called proof of work. Are there good non-technical articles providing a good overview on this issue?

**Note:** By non-technical I mean I am not interested in articles providing codes and written for computer scientists only. I want something a researcher in business could understand and get the general picture in a certain depth.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says very clearly that questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic. You may want to spend some time reading the [help] pages to better understand what is (and is not) proper to ask here before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an online course with some free materials, which may be a little more technical than you are hoping, but you have to get a little technical to understand it. Free materials are available at https://jbaczuk.github.io/blockchain_fundamentals. Here is some info, if you have any specific questions about proof of work, please add it and I’ll try to answer for you.

## Proof of Work

Proof of work is what a miner must provide with their block candidate in order for the network to consider that block valid. A proof of work is given as a 32 byte value which is calculated using the block data and a hash function, so it is called a block hash.

#### Finding a valid block hash

This step is the process commonly referred to as mining. This is where the most work is done, and provides the basis for a secure network.

**Block Hash**

The block hash is created by taking the block header, and providing it as an input to the SHA256 hashing algorithm. The nonce is continually changed until a valid solution is found. Miners are, quite literally, optimized guessing machines hoping the next random nonce will result in a valid hash. The fastest, most power efficient hardware will be the most profitable. Power costs and air temperature in a given region will also affect mining profitability.

**Hash Functions**

Hash functions are [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), meaning they can only be computed in one direction. You can easily hash an input, but you cannot calculate an input that will result in a specific output. In order to do so, you have to keep providing a new random input until the solution is found. In Bitcoin, this is also known as work, the number of guesses, on average, that a miner must make in order to calculate a valid hash.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your attention. Your comments are very enlightening. What seems to be quite dificult for me is to understand the mechanism behind PoW. I've read that this is done by a machine solving some combinatorial problem and then the other miners accepting it in some way but every time I see some example of how this proccess occur in practice, I get a little lost on technical terms.

Comment: It’s a hash algorithm. You get a random output (the output is a really large number) for a given input (the block header data), but it is always the same output for the same input (it’s deterministic). To be a valid output (a valid hash), it must be below the target value the network agrees on. Other nodes verify this new block by taking the same block header and running the hash algorithm to prove the output (the block hash) is below the network target value.